# Redirecting URL with anchors to external URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am redirecting couple of rails paths to external absolute url's.

```
get 'xyz' => redirect("www.example.com")
```

However, I am unable to redirect paths with anchors:

```
get 'abc/def#xyz' => redirect("www.another-example.com")
```

Is it possible to achieve what I am trying to do in a Rails 4 application?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it's impossible. Server doesn't see anchors, # symbol is commonly used in routes.rb to split controller and action name. Anchors themself are used only by browsers. Also remember about 'http://' when you redirect to external URL ;)